# How to add row in SQL if value from one column is greater than the value in another column

Tags: sql-server

An example of my dataset would be:

ZoneA: 0-100

ZoneB: 100-200

```
Name  SubName  startValueA  endValueA  startValueB  endValueB
A     X        0            25         0            100
A     X        25           35         0            100 
A     X        35           80         0            100 
A     X        80           95         0            100 
A     X        95           120        0            100 
A     Y        120          145        100          200 
A     Y        145          160        100          200 
A     Y        160          175        100          200 
A     Y        175          190        100          200 
A     Y        190          200        100          200
```

Essentially what I'm desiring is this:

```
Name  SubName  startValueA  endValueA  startValueB  endValueB  Percent
A     X        0            25         0            100        1
A     X        25           35         0            100        1
A     X        35           80         0            100        1    
A     X        80           95         0            100        1    
A     X        95           100        0            100        .2   <--- (100-95)/(120-95)
A     X        100          120        100          200        .8   <--- (120-100)/(120-95)
A     Y        120          145        100          200        1    
A     Y        145          160        100          200        1 
A     Y        160          175        100          200        1
A     Y        175          190        100          200        1
A     Y        190          200        100          200        1
```

So a row is added where ValueA crosses over ValueB, and then the resulting percent of each is calculated. Basically I'm trying to figure out how much of valueA belongs in each Zone as defined by valueB. I have the first row done pretty simply with something along the lines of:

```
case 
   when endValueA <= endValueB then 1 
   else ((endValueB - startValueA)/(endValueA - startValueA))
```

I'm just not sure how to get the additional row added in with the inverse percent.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: if you mess up the formula at least you should redo the image. But again is better if you post data as text

Comment: When you create a row for X you change endValueB from 100 to 200. What is the logic there?

Comment: Basically ZoneA is 0-100. ZoneB is 100-200. My query thus for brings in the starting and ending value for the Zone and tries to identify which zone the A Values fall in based on the startValue. I can always bring in the Zone easily - but would like to break it out first. Changing endValueB to 100-200 is to signify that the Zone has changed.

Comment: I opened the question. Thought "I can't be bothered to type that example data" and am now closing it again. If you want people to help you supply example data as text

Comment: Typed out the example data

Comment: Do you want to display the data via a `view` or a `query` or update the table data?

Comment: so what happen if on the last row endValueA  is 300?? What would be the new row?

Comment: There would be a Zone3 that would also need data added for it. So another row would be added. It's very unlikely that would happen though. But if it went into another zone, the percentage would need to be broken up into 3 chunks